# How to Remove Mask or Corrupted Image from PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, poppler

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application to extract text and images from PDF files. While extracting images few of them get corrupted.

Is there any way to identify those corrupted images after extraction? Anyone know why they get corrupted?

I am using `pdftohtml` and `pdftotext` (poppler) Ubuntu utilities.

Thanks in advance.